# Problem with output, possible variable problem

Tags: python, sql

I've been trying to get this working for quite a bit and I can't get my head around.

What I want is to output all the `rows` that were saved one hour after the `row` that I'm searching for.

Line:

```
if x.lower() == 'full name':
         specify_name = input('Please insert full name. \n ')
         select_query = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack WHERE NAME ==(?) ''', (specify_name,))
         for row in c.fetchall():
             print('\nName:', row[0])
             print('Email:', row[1])
             print('Phone Number:', row[2])
             print('Date and Time:', row[3])
             print('Venue:', row[4])
             print('\n')
             d = row[3]
             print(d)
             c.execute('''SELECT *
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ?
             AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')  ''', (d,d))
             print('Matching Results: \n ')
             for rows in c.fetchall():
                 print(row)
             menu()
```

Output so far:

```
Name: Alejandro Trinchero
Email: Ale@
Phone Number: 11
Date and Time: 2021-02-10 16:34:37
Venue: nameofvenue


2021-02-10 16:34:37
Matching Results:

('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
```

Problem right now: It's showing me 4 times the same `row` but no other `rows` that share the hour.

Full code:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect('covid.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def enter_data():
    def create_table():
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        covidTrack(
        name TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        ph_number INTEGER,
        datestamp TEXT,
        keyword TEXT)''')

    i_name = str(input('Please insert FULL NAME : \n ...'))

    i_email = str(input('Please insert EMAIL : \n ...'))

    i_number = int(input('Please insert PHONE NUMBER : \n ...'))


    print('Your data has been saved for acelerated contact, thank you. \n')
    time.sleep(1)


    def data_entry():
        date, keyword = dynamic_data_entry()
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO covidTrack
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (i_name, i_email, i_number, date, keyword))
        conn.commit()


    def dynamic_data_entry():
        keyword = 'nameofvenue'
        date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        return date, keyword
        conn.commit()

    def read_from_db():
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack''')
        conn.commit()

    create_table()
    data_entry()
    read_from_db()
    menu()

def data_search():
    x = input('''Select desired search: \n
    Search by FULL NAME. \n
    Search by DATE AND TIME. \n
    Search by PHONE NUMBER. \n
    Exit.
    ~
    ''')

    if x.lower() == 'full name':
         specify_name = input('Please insert full name. \n ')
         select_query = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack WHERE NAME ==(?) ''', (specify_name,))
         for row in c.fetchall():
             print('\nName:', row[0])
             print('Email:', row[1])
             print('Phone Number:', row[2])
             print('Date and Time:', row[3])
             print('Venue:', row[4])
             print('\n')
             d = row[3]
             print(d)
             c.execute('''SELECT *
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ?
             AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')  ''', (d,d))
             print('Matching Results: \n ')
             for rows in c.fetchall():
                 print(row)
             menu()

    if x.lower() == 'date and time':
        specify_datestamp = input('''Please insert full date as shown.
        \n
        Please follow this format...
        \n
        YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ''')

        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack WHERE datestamp == ? ''', (specify_datestamp,))
        for row in c.fetchall():
             print('\nName:', row[0])
             print('Email:', row[1])
             print('Phone Number:', row[2])
             print('Date and Time:', row[3])
             print('Venue:', row[4])
             print('\n')
             d = row[3]

             c.execute('''SELECT *
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ?
             AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')  ''',(d,d))
             print('Matching Results: \n')
             for rows in c.fetchall():
                 print(row[0:4])
             menu()

    if x.lower() == 'phone number':
        specify_ph_number = input('''Please insert phone number as shown.
        \n
        > 1234567890 <
        \n''')
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack
        WHERE ph_number == ? ''', (specify_ph_number,))
        for row in c.fetchall():
             print('\nName:', row[0])
             print('Email:', row[1])
             print('Phone Number:', row[2])
             print('Date and Time:', row[3])
             print('Venue:', row[4])
             print('\n')
             d = row[3]

             c.execute('''SELECT (*)
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ?
             AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours') ''',(d,d))
             print('Matching Results: \n')
             for rows in c.fetchall():
                 print(row[0:4])
             menu()

    if x.lower() == 'exit':
        exit()

def menu():
    choose_funtion = input('''Please choose action: \n
    A TO ENTER DATA. \n
    B TO SEARCH DATA. \n
    EXIT \n ''')

    if choose_funtion.lower() == 'a':
        print('You choose enter data.')
        enter_data()
    if choose_funtion.lower() == 'b':
        print('You choose search data.')
        data_search()
    if choose_funtion.lower() == 'exit':
        exit()
menu()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh To be honest I'm not familiar as well, I found this the closest to the `INTERVAL` statement. I'm not quite sure that it is correct but is as far as I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the wrong variable in the second loop:

```py
         for row in c.fetchall():
             c.execute(...)
             for rows in c.fetchall():
                 print(row)
```

You use the variable `row` defined in the first `for` loop. That's why the output under `Matching Results:` is all the same.

You may want to do

```py
         for row in c.fetchall():
             c.execute(...)
             for row2 in c.fetchall():
                 print(row2)
```

Comment: You're a great person! You can't imagine how much time I spent trying to look for the mistake. I thought because I was using `rows` instead of `row` and `print` inside the loop the variable would be kind of "Isolated". Thank you so much.

Comment: Output now: `Matching Results:

('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')


('Sarah Daniels', 'Sarah@', 22, '2021-02-10 16:34:46', 'nameofvenue')


('Martin F', 'Mar@', 55, '2021-02-10 16:59:29', 'nameofvenue')


('Jorge X', 'Jor@', 44, '2021-02-10 17:00:36', 'nameofvenue')`

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero Glad to see that you get the desired output :). If there is anything I can help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Could it have something to do with this line:

```
print('\nName:', row[0])
```

I see the #\n only on the one row and at the final row:

```
print('\n')
```

Or it could be the:

```
d = row[3]
print(d)
```

From what I see it looks like you're just printing out the third row?
You may need to use row in range[3] or a for loop.

Row[3] has date and time, and that's what shows in the output.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It's true that those lines are a bit dodgy but anyway I did change to `print(\n)` and to `(row[3],row[3]`. Working perfectly fine and looking even better but still the same result as with the dodgy lines, just the same row 4 times printed in matches. `Matching Results:

('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')`